# InnoDB deadlock with concurrent SELECT .. FOR UPDATE queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7, deadlock

I'm currently having deadlocks during high load scenarios.
These deadlocks occur even without any update, insert or delete statements
Also changing isolation level to read committed does not help either, transaction isolation level used by application is repeatable read.
Access to the rows are done in ordered manner, statements are also in the same order in all transactions.
MySQL Server version:  5.7.12

I can reproduce this behavior with following example when I run 50 requests per second

Let's say this is the table

```sql
CREATE TABLE post (
  `id` INT(10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author_id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
  `group` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UNIQUE INDEX unique_author_group (`author_id` ASC, `group` ASC),
  INDEX `idx_updated_at` (updated_at ASC)
);
```

And this would be the query that is causing deadlocks during high load situations, this query utilizes the index `unique_author_group` but even if I try to SELECT with PRIMARY key deadlock occurs:

```sql
SELECT * FROM post WHERE author_id = ? FOR UPDATE;
```

Whole DB transaction would look like this:

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM post WHERE author_id = ? FOR UPDATE;

COMMIT;
-- or rollback if deadlock occurs
ROLLBACK;
```

And the deadlock would be like this:

```
Reported lock type: RECORD
Lock mode: X for both transactions
idx: unique_author_group for both transactions
txn time: 0
```

(from Comment)

From the logs it looks like this, and all of this happens within 150ms beginning to end.

1. Transaction A requests lock for author 1
2. Transaction A is granted lock
3. Transaction B requests lock for author 1
4. Transaction C requests lock for author 1
5. Transaction A commits transaction
6. Transaction C gets deadlock
7. Transaction B is granted lock

Out of 9 concurrent transactions 3 of those gets rolled back as deadlock victim.

Comment: How many rows?  Do you have any `FOREIGN KEYs`?

Comment: Do _both_ transactions look the same?  Is there anything else in the transaction?  Are the battling connections asking for the same author?  How many rows in the table?  How many rows for _that_ author?

Comment: @RickJames in total 40 thousand rows, no foreign keys. There isn't anything else in the transaction only the aforementioned select is enough to cause deadlock. Yes connections are querying for the same author, rows for that specific author 5.

Comment: @RickJames also the reason there is only SELECT in this transaction is because I've been trying to narrow down queries that cause deadlock and it just turned out that it's the SELECT FOR UPDATE statement.

Comment: A typical, simple, deadlock involves two statements in each connection and they need to access two rows in a different order.  `WHERE author_id = ?` locks all the rows with that author.  I can't see what else is involved.

Comment: Exactly, this is why I just can't wrap my head around it. I wonder if the MySQL server configuration has something to do with it.

Comment: Another question that might help me answer you...  How long does a transaction take?  (Instrument the code to get millisecond-precision timing.)  What percent of the transactions end in a deadlock?  Do you have code to re-run the transaction when a deadlock occurs?

Comment: From the logs it looks like this, and all of this happens within 150ms beginning to end.
1. Transaction A requests lock for author 1
2. Transaction A is granted lock
3. Transaction B requests lock for author 1
4. Transaction C requests lock for author 1
5. Transaction A commits transaction
6. Transaction C gets deadlock
7. Transaction B is granted lock
Out of 9 concurrent transactions 3 of those gets rolled back as deadlock victim.

Comment: Does "A" `UPDATE` or `DELETE` or `INSERT` any rows?